# How can I retrieve "remembered"(stored) wi-fi password from a win. 7 device?

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

I have access to PC, and I am a standard user. Everything(incl. "show charecters" tickbox at wiriless menu) requires admin access.
Now, that said machine is actually like a big tv with touch. Type-stuff is handled by virtual keyboard of windows.

I can reach to 
c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces and can see-open files there, which is I assume where passwords stored are. Now the problem is that these passwords is encypted.

I'm ok with if there is a way with changing/resetting admin password as well. Considering this device has nothing but massive amounts of usb(yep, not even cd-dvd // rw) the only way is from inside or with usb without admin rights.

Comment: Why don't you just change the user group of the user and/or give admin access when its requested?

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely give WirelessKeyView a try. It is built by the same person who creates all the NirSoft utilities, and is free to use. You might not need to worry about any encryption, as I have used it countless times on many computers and have never had an issue.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html

Below is an image of what its interface looks like:
[image]

Comment: Its what I need but my problem is that I cant run exe files because I dont have admin access.

Comment: I apologize. I should have read your question more thoroughly. If this is your computer, there are ways to obtain admin access with tools like Ultimate BootCD and Hiren's boot CD. If this isn't your own machine, I can't suggest enough you go through proper channels to obtain what you're looking for; assuming it is a work PC you are much better off asking an administrator for help rather than getting caught by an administrator mucking with system files (but of course, this is more advice than it is support, so take with a grain of salt)

Answer (score 3):

In Command Prompt try:

`netsh wlan show profiles (name of network you need the password to) key=clear`

Example:

`netsh wlan show profiles example key=clear`

The password should show up under security settings key content.

Answer (score 2):

From [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/116934/how-to-view-that-forgotten-wireless-network-password-in-windows/), this tutorial will walk you thorugh how to recover the password, however you will need to work with whoever is the administrator of the machine to get admin access to do the final steps.

> To view your wireless network password we need to get to the settings
>   for your network adapter, so press the Win + R keyboard combination
>   and type ncpa.cpl in the run box, then hit the enter key.
>  [image]
>  You will now see all the network
>   adapters in your machine, right-click on the wireless one and select
>   Status from the context menu.
>  [image]
>  When the Wi-Fi Status dialog loads up, click on the
>   Wireless Properties button.
>  [image]
>   Then you will need to switch over to the Security tab.
>  [image]
>  Finally, check the Show characters
>   checkbox to reveal your password.
>  [image]
>  That’s all there is to it.

Comment: He doesn't have the Administrator password. Otherwise, I would have voted up on this one

Comment: @Luke As I said in the answer, he will need to work with the system administrator. Most people are reasonable if you ask nicely, unless you are doing something you should not be doing (like trying to get on to the work Wi-Fi without clearing it with IT) then you should not be doing it anyway.

Comment: Agreed, and sorry, I didn't notice that in the answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Cain & Abel password recovery. One possible download site is http://www.oxid.it/cain.html. I think it can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

As awesome as WirelessKeyView (and I'm sure other tools too) are, they require admin access to pull the passwords.

Your best (and only) bet is first to remove the admin password if you don't know what it is:

1. Download Hiren's: http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/
2. Copy it to a USB drive: http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd-on-usb-disk
3. Boot from the USB drive
4. It will present you with a DOS-ish menu, select DOS programs then, if memory serves me right, the password recovery tools are in option 1 (or 3?)
5. Active Password Changer works best and is the easiest to use
6. Restart, login as admin and now you can recover your wireless password